# How do I get my project working after my MAC has been formattted

Tags: angular, firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I had issues that forced me to format my MAC.  I uploaded my Ionic Cordova Firebase project to Github and cloned the directory but I'm getting errors running NPM install to get it back to a working project.

When I run SUDO NPM INSTALL i get the following errors:

```js
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/blah/Development/AppName/node_modules/fsevents/build'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/blah/Development/AppName/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node" "--module_name=fse" "--module_path=/Users/blah/Development/AppName/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64" "--napi_version=4" "--node_abi_napi=napi"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/blah/Development/AppName/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v12.6.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/blah/Development/AppName/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/blah/Development/AppName/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64 --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<blah> (/Users/blah/Development/AppName/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:203:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.6.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/blah/Development/AppName/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/blah/Development/AppName/node_modules/fsevents
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.6.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.10.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/blah/Development/AppName/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/blah/Development/AppName/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64 --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)

> grpc@1.18.0 install /Users/blah/Development/AppName/node_modules/grpc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.18.0/node-v72-darwin-x64-unknown.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.18.0 and node@12.6.0 (node-v72 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/blah/Development/AppName/node_modules/grpc/build'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=/Users/blah/Development/AppName/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=/Users/blah/Development/AppName/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-darwin-x64-unknown" "--napi_version=4" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v72"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/blah/Development/AppName/node_modules/grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v12.6.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/Users/blah/Development/AppName/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/Users/blah/Development/AppName/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-darwin-x64-unknown --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<blah> (/Users/blah/Development/AppName/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:203:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.6.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/blah/Development/AppName/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/blah/Development/AppName/node_modules/grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.6.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.12.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/Users/blah/Development/AppName/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/Users/blah/Development/AppName/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-darwin-x64-unknown --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
npm WARN @agm/core@1.0.0-beta.5 requires a peer of @angular/common@^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @agm/core@1.0.0-beta.5 requires a peer of @angular/core@^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ionic-native/camera@5.2.0 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^5.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ionic-native/crop@5.2.0 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^5.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ionic-native/google-plus@5.2.0 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^5.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ionic-native/ionic-webview@5.2.0 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^5.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ionic-native/splash-screen@5.2.0 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^5.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ionic-native/status-bar@5.2.0 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^5.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.4.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.9.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 install: `node install`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! grpc@1.18.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.18.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I was thinking NPM install would install all of the dependencies for this project.

Comment: Can you at least make an effort to format that huge dump of the error output to make it readable?

Answer (score 1):

This is a permissions issue most likely, based on the error `gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied` in line 2.

If deleting node_modules and running `npm install` (no sudo) doesn't work, you should try running `sudo chmod 777` on your node_modules folder and try again.

If all else fails you can also try to rebuild `node-gyp` with `sudo node-gyp rebuild -g --unsafe-perm`.

Comment: That didn't work.  Although I got a different error once I installed gyp.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56962522/unable-to-run-npm-install-for-a-project-i-cloned-from-github-after-formatting-my

Answer (score 1):

I got this working by downgrading my Node version. Apparently it's latest version is incompatible with GRPC