# Unable to run NPM INSTALL for a project I cloned from Github after formatting my MAC

Tags: angular, firebase, cordova, ionic-framework

Here is the result of sudo npm install.  I had to format my MAC and lost everything.  I pushed my project to my github repo and cloned it locally afterwards.  So now I'm trying to install all of the dependencies but get the following error.

```js
3 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/grpc_node/ext/byte_buffer.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:203:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=/Users/anonymous/Development/Mundo1.5/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=/Users/anonymous/Development/Mundo1.5/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-darwin-x64-unknown" "--napi_version=4" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v72"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/anonymous/Development/Mundo1.5/node_modules/grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v12.6.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/Users/anonymous/Development/Mundo1.5/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/Users/anonymous/Development/Mundo1.5/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-darwin-x64-unknown --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/anonymous/Development/Mundo1.5/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:203:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.6.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/anonymous/Development/Mundo1.5/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/anonymous/Development/Mundo1.5/node_modules/grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.6.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.12.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/Users/anonymous/Development/Mundo1.5/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/Users/anonymous/Development/Mundo1.5/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-darwin-x64-unknown --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! grpc@1.18.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have right permission on the project folder. You can use the following command to npm install

```
sudo npm install --unsafe-perm
```

And you can rebuild node-gyp with

```
sudo node-gyp rebuild -g --unsafe-perm
```

Comment: Running sudo node-gyp rebuild -g --unsafe-perm generates the following error:
ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:323:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:203:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild" "-g" "--unsafe-perm"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/anonymous/Development/Mundo1.5

Comment: Running sudo npm install --unsafe-perm gives me:
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:356:58: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
../../nan/nan_object_wrap.h:24:25: error: no member named 'IsNearDeath' in 'Nan::Persistent<v8::Object,
./fsevents.cc:76:16: error: variable has incomplete type 'void'
void FSEvents::Initialize(v8::Handle<v8::Object> exports) {
build error 
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/anonymous/Development//node_modules/grpc
npm ERR! grpc@1.18.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library